# Use Python to Append ESRI File Geodatabase to SQLexpress Geodatabase

Tags: append, arcgis, arcpy

I have a set of file geodatabases with the same schema as my SQLexpress geodatabase.  Using this script, I am trying to append the feature classes of each FGDB into the corresponding feature class in the SQLexpress GDB.

```
import arcpy, os

inputGDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
sqlDB = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.env.workspace = sqlDB

sqlFCs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in sqlFCs:
    sourceFC = str(fc)[14:]
    if arcpy.Exists(os.path.join(inputGDB, sourceFC)):
        arcpy.AddMessage("Appending " + sourceFC + " to " + fc)
        fcPath = sqlDB + "\\" + fc
        arcpy.Append_management(os.path.join(inputGDB,sourceFC), fcPath)
```

When I attempt this with my python script, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 000732
Target Dataset: Dataset Database Servers\WOS2UA52417ZT_SQLEXPRESS.gds\SCAT_Data (VERSION:dbo.DEFAULT)\SCAT_Data.DBO.trackjsonpnts does not exist or is not supported
```

It is the same if I try to simply use the Append tool from ArcToolbox.  Is there a way to append feature classes in an SQL database?

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/225565/115

Comment: I have gotten this exact script to work if I reference the SQL geodatabase via Database Connections in ArcCatalog.  However, I am unable to reference the same SQL geodatabase via Database Servers, even though the data is visible in ArcCatalog.

Comment: @spaine is correct.  The Database Servers connection builds up a connection string that most geoprocessing tools don't expect.  Use the Add Database button to open the Connection Properties dialog, use "WOS2UA52417ZT\SQLEXPRESS" as the Instance value, select the target database.  This gives you a ".sde" file that geoprocessing tools can understand.